# My program won't invoke my methods

Tags: java

I've only just begun programming, and I find most of my resources to be incredibly unhelpful. Hopefully you guys can help!

My program runs until it gets to the display methods, and then it just stops. No errors, and no build successful. It just continues with the user input. Any ideas?

Here is all of the program. I created a separate class for the object as well. Let me know if you think the problem could be there. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HernandezMortgageCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        programDescription();
        System.out.println();

        MortgageLoan mortgageLoan1 = new MortgageLoan();

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please enter the home buyer's last name: ");
        String lastName = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the home's zip code: ");
        String zipCode = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter the home value: ");  
        double homeValue = userInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the annual interest rate: ");
        double annualInterestRate = userInput.nextDouble();

        mortgageLoan1.setLoanIdentifier(mortgageLoan1.getLoanIdentifier());
        mortgageLoan1.setHomeValue(userInput.nextDouble());
        mortgageLoan1.setLoanAmount();
        mortgageLoan1.setAnnualInterestRate(userInput.nextDouble());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        displayLoanDetails(mortgageLoan1);
        displayMortgageResults(mortgageLoan1); 

    }
public static void programDescription() {
    System.out.println("This program implements a Mortgage Calulator");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Given a home's purchase price and loan's annual" +
                       "interest rate, it will compute the monthly" +
                       "mortgage payment, which includes taxes, " +
                       "insurance principle and interest.");
}
public static void displayLoanDetails(MortgageLoan mortgageLoan1){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Loan Details");
    System.out.printf("  Loan identifier             %f "
                      + mortgageLoan1.getLoanIdentifier());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("  Loan amount                 %.2f "
                      + mortgageLoan1.getLoanAmount() );
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("  Loan length                 %f "
                      + mortgageLoan1.getLengthOfLoan() + " years");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("  Annual Interest Rate        %.3f"
                      + mortgageLoan1.getAnnualInterestRate() + "%");
    System.out.println();
}
public static void displayMortgageResults (MortgageLoan mortgageLoan1) {
   double monthlyPropertyTax = mortgageLoan1.calcMonthlyPropertyTax();
   double monthlyInsurancePremium = 
                               mortgageLoan1.calcMonthlyInsurancePremium();  
   double monthlyPrincipleAndLoan = 
                                mortgageLoan1.calcMonthlyPrincipleAndLoan(); 
   double totalMonthlyMortgage = monthlyPropertyTax + monthlyInsurancePremium
                               + monthlyPrincipleAndLoan;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Monthly Mortgage Payment");
    System.out.printf("  Monthly Taxes                  %.2f",
                      monthlyPropertyTax);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf(" Monthly Insurance             %.2f",
                       monthlyInsurancePremium);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("  Monthly Principle & Interest   %.2f",
                      monthlyPrincipleAndLoan);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("                               --------");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("  Total Monthly Mortage Payment  %.2f", 
                      totalMonthlyMortgage);
 } 

public class MortgageLoan {
    private String loanIdentifier;
    private double homeValue;
    private double downPayment;
    private double loanAmount;
    private int lengthOfLoan;
    private double annualInterestRate;

    public MortgageLoan() {
       loanIdentifier = "";
       homeValue = 0.0;
       downPayment = 10.0;
       loanAmount = 0.0;
       lengthOfLoan = 30;
       annualInterestRate = 0.0;
    }
    public static char firstFour(String lastName){
       char result = lastName.charAt(0);
       result += lastName.charAt(1);
       result += lastName.charAt(2);
       result += lastName.charAt(3);
       return result;
    }
    public static char firstThree(String zipCode){
      char result = zipCode.charAt(0);
      result += zipCode.charAt(1);
      result += zipCode.charAt(2);
      return result; 
    }

    public static String lastNameZipCode(String lastName, String zipCode) {
       String result = "";
       result = lastName.toUpperCase();
       result += firstFour(lastName);
       result += firstThree(zipCode);
       return result;
}

    void setLoanIdentifier(String lastNameZipCode) {
        loanIdentifier = lastNameZipCode;
    }
    void setHomeValue(double newHomeValue) {
        homeValue = newHomeValue;
    }
    void setLoanAmount() {
        double newLoanAmount = homeValue - homeValue * (downPayment/100);
        loanAmount = newLoanAmount;
    }
    void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate) {
        annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
    }

    public String getLoanIdentifier() {
    return loanIdentifier;
    }

    public double getLoanAmount(){
        return loanAmount;
    }

    public int getLengthOfLoan(){
        return lengthOfLoan;
    }

    public double getAnnualInterestRate(){
        return annualInterestRate;
    }

public double calcMonthlyPropertyTax() {
    final double HOME_ASSED_VALUE_PERCENTAGE = 0.85;
    final double ANNUAL_PROPERTY_TAXES_PERCENTAGE = 0.0063;
    final double ADMIN_FEE = 35.00;
    double homeAssessedValue = homeValue * HOME_ASSED_VALUE_PERCENTAGE;
    double annualPropertyTaxes = (homeAssessedValue *
                              ANNUAL_PROPERTY_TAXES_PERCENTAGE + ADMIN_FEE);
    double monthlyPropertyTax = annualPropertyTaxes/12;
    return monthlyPropertyTax;
}

public double calcMonthlyInsurancePremium() {
    final double ANNUAL_PREMIUM_PERCENTAGE = .0049;
    double annualInsurancePremium = .0049 * homeValue;
    double monthlyInsurancePremium = Math.round(annualInsurancePremium/12);
    return monthlyInsurancePremium;
}

public double calcMonthlyPrincipleAndLoan(){
    double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/100/12;
    double Factor = Math.exp((lengthOfLoan*12) * Math.log   
                   (monthlyInterestRate + 1));
    double monthlyPrincipleAndLoan = (Factor * monthlyInterestRate *
                                      loanAmount)/(Factor - 1);
    return monthlyPrincipleAndLoan;

  }
}
```

Comment: You're not using your variables you store from the scanner. You're calling `nextDouble` etc. twice, so your program will wait for twice as many inputs. Also, I would say that SO isn't really the place for this. If you can narrow down your problem first, then maybe.

Comment: please add MortgageLoan class in your post

Comment: @1blustone then where is? Like I said, I'm a new programmer. I don't know even know what my problem is, so how could I narrow it down? I'm trying to call the variables I stored in my class method, as well as the ones the user stored.

Comment: what I meant is you're defining `homeValue` in your main method, but you're writing `mortgageLoan1.setHomeValue(userInput.nextDouble());` instead of `mortgageLoan1.setHomeValue(homeValue);` - instead of using the stored value the program queries user input a second time.

Comment: that fixed it at least to the point where I can see the errors

Comment: any ideas on what to enter for loan amount? when I enter mortgageLoan1.getLoanAmount, it can't find the variable. It worked for the loan identifier though

Comment: Please read [mcve] and specially read the very helpful page linked at its bottom on debugging small programs.